Playwright as package - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(testType)')
I have a playwright package written using typescript with custom fixtures.
Package has bin like that:
{
  "bin": {
    "example": "./src/abc.js"
  }
}

Executable run some script that triggers playwright tests. Tests use fixtures that are merged:
import { mergeTests } from '@playwright/test';

export const test = mergeTests(example1, example2);

Before bin running package was compiled with tsc:
yarn tsc --build

tsconfig contains:
"target": "NodeNext",
"module": "NodeNext"

The package was built successfully with .js d.ts and js.map files.
After that, if I ran bin, that trigger playwright test with config, I got an error in the index file that aggregated fixtures with mergeTests:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(testType)')

P.S. Tests are worked fine without package compilation to .js
Tryed to 'play' with package, tsconfig, target/module.

Please share your package.json so we can see which versions this involves.
